# Reviewing suggested edits (rendered output): show links when they are hightlighted

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

The issue is simple: on the following screenshot one can't see that "RequireJS" and "HeadJS" are actually links: somewhy they have the same text color as the ordinary text, not blue, like links. This is a relatively simple case: I saw that the links got disappeared and checked the markdown; however, there can be less obvious cases when an added link is irrelevant and one can miss that a link has even been added. Why links are not highlighted anyway? I suggest to make them visible like in any post.

[image]

Comment: This is one reason why you should always check the markdown diff too.

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [Suggested edits that change links should jump out and punch reviewers in the face](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/142919)

Comment: @MartijnPieters not quite: I'm talking about links being not visible, even if they are not changed (text may got changed without a changing a link's target). But the duplicate suggestion by Cody Gray looks suitable.